# Can i alias column name from query result?

Tags: sql, oracle, alias

Can i alias column name from query result? Why this query doesn't work?

```
select 

  column_code AS (select column_name from column_registers where column_registers_id = column_code) 

from other_table;
```

My GOAL is "COLUMN NAME ALIASED" by query result.
Thanks.

Comment: ya you can but its depends on how you are using you query seems like ok have you got any error?

Comment: You'd have to use dynamic SQL if you want,but note the alias applies to the column therefore all rows have the same alias. you cannot vary the alias row by row

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this

```
select 

    (select column_name from column_registers where column_registers_id = column_code) AS column_code 

    from other_table;
```

Comment: No, you cannot dynamically set an alias or column name in standard SQL.